# Separate two numbers which are joined by a dash

Tags: php

Could anyone please tell me how I can separate the following numbers.

```
12255252-675765675
```

So they can be called separately:

```
$number1 = 12255252;

$number2 = 675765675;
```

Comment: For completeness, you could use the [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function, but [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is better for a simple case such as this.

Answer (score 4):

use [explode](http://uk.php.net/explode):

```
$number = '12255252-675765675';
$exp = explode('-', $number);
echo $exp[0]."<br />";
echo $exp[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = explode('-', $yournumber);
$number1 = $result[0];
$number2 = $result[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$number = '12255252-675765675';
list($number1, $number2) = explode('-', $number);
```

Comment: I have received requests to edit this, saying that "list" is depreciated in newer versions of PHP. However http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php does not list anything about being depreciated.  If it has indeed be depreciated, please point me to that so I can correct my statement.

Comment: You probably meant ["deprecated"](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/D/deprecated.html) where you said ["depreciated"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/depreciate).

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode to separate it.

```
<?php
$number = '12255252-675765675';
$new_arr = explode('-', $number);
echo $new_arr[0]; // returns 12255252
echo $new_arr[1]; // returns 675765675
?>
```

[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) documentation here.